# Can't connect remotely to MySQL Server with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Every time when I'm trying to connect remote mysql server through workbench. It gives me an error

> can't connect mysql on remote server '10061'

But I am able to connect with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL on default only listens to localhost as a security precaution. You might need to make sure MySQL is listening on your external IP interface:
Follow the steps:

nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Edit the MySQL configuration file on your server and go to the following line:

*bind-address = 127.0.0.1*

The IP address 127.0.0.1 means your MySQL is only listening localhost. Change it to

*bind-address = 0.0.0.0*

Now MySQL will listen all IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add following lines to my.cnf in mysqld section

   bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
2. Restart mysql service
3. Fire following query(on machine to which you want to connect)

i. create new user and password and grand privileges to that IP

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO u_name@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

ii. To overwrite privilege

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`