# mysql workbench can't connect to database but connection test is ok

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a mysql server with user 'root' and no password.
When I do mysql -u root -p in a terminal I can connect to my server.
When I use mysql workbench, if I  test this connection, it s successful.
But when I try to connect to the server with mysql workbench I am getting this error :

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to
>   server at 127.0.0.1:3306:   Could not open database
>
> Please: 1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
>    2 Check that
>   mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can
>   be changed)
>   3 Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from
>   your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the
>   server and from which machines)
>   4 Make sure you are both providing a
>   password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1
>   connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Does anybody know what's going wrong here?

**[UPDATE]**
I am still having this problem.
With mysql workbench : test connection is ok, but I cannot connect to mysql server.
If this can help, here is mysql server status :
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

```
Connection id:      7
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         50 sec

Threads: 3  Questions: 69  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 67  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 60  Queries per second avg: 1.380
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same problem myself.

I can overcome it by running Mysql Workbench 'as administrator'. (close any running instances. right click it from the start menu, and choose 'run as administrator'.)

It just won't connect if I don't run it with elevated privileges. So it must be some kind of flaw or bug in Workbench.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you set something in the:

```
[Preferences -> Modeling -> MySQL -> Default Target MySQL Version]
```

Clear it and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The last comment on [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71605) bug report worked for me ...

> [7 Jul 2016 18:33] Gaurav Vasistha
>
> Solved for windows 7 64 bit mysql workbench 6.0 CE solution is weird
>   but it works  so just give it a try
>
> 1. Go to Start.
> 2. Type %temp% in the search box and then click the Temp folder item that appears at the top.
> 3. At the top of the Explorer window, in the address bar, click the folder to the left of Temp in the folder path (Local by default).
> 4. In the folder list, right-click the Temp folder and then click Properties and then click the Security tab.
> 5. Click the Edit button and on the next screen click Add.
> 6. On the next screen, in the large text window type Everyone and then click Check Names - Everyone should then be underlined.
> 7. Check the box for Full control under the Allow column, and then click OK, then OK again, and OK again to close all the windows.
>
> I discovered this while trying to uninstall workbench in order to
>   reinstall it and while installing it gave an error message  "the
>   installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package
>   2203 windows 7"

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the very same issue

at my local instance I have started originally the mysql-workbench with sudo and because of that some directories and files were assigned to root in the ~/.mysql/workbench/ folder, so I have deleted the full directory(~/.mysql/workbench/) and all was OK at the next run

Comment: I also encountered this problem. It was confusing as for a clean install of mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 18.10 I had to access the server using socket by running workbench as root (that allows no password connection as root). Then after setting up tcp I was unable to connect (as regular user), yet "test connection" was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the way I solved it was to run the workbench as **root** command with

```
 sudo mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. I could connect using terminal but not using workbench.

In addition, I could not connect localhost with

```
sudo mysql-workbench
```

as well.

So, I follow these steps and it worked for me: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/access-denied-for-user-root-localhost

I run this command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'insert_password';
```

and then it was possible to access without admin privileges using the password 'insert_password' in the workbench.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal client does an automatic fallback, which MySQL Workbench does not. If the connection via TCP/IP fails then the terminal client attempts to connect via sockets. If your server is configured to use sockets then you have to use this method also in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: My server is installed by default. It has always worked. But on this new PC, with new Ubuntu 15.10, I have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after trying everything suggested here, this solved my issue:

[Can't connect remotely to MySQL Server with MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078671/9216582)

Answer (score 0):

note: in my solution I had used these commands to solve this problem

```
1004  sudo launchctl list | grep mysql\n
1005  sudo launchctl stop com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld\n
1006  lsof -i :3306\n
1010  ps aux | grep mysql\n
1011  sudo kill -9
1012  sudo kill -9
1013  sudo kill -9
```

because I had to stop other process that using mysql.
I answered because this is still a problem